# How to Ignore lines with StreamWriter WriteLine

Tags: powershell, streamwriter, streamwriter.write

trying to figure out how to ignore or stop specific lines from being written to file with StreamWriter. Here is the code I'm working with from [How to pass arguments to program when using variable as path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72118674) :

```
$LogDir     = "c:\users\user" # Log file output directory
$PlinkDir   = "C:"            # plink.exe directory
$SerialIP   = "1.1.1.1"       # serial device IP address
$SerialPort = 10000           # port to log

function CaptureWeight {
    Start-Job -Name WeightLog -ScriptBlock {
        filter timestamp {
            $sw.WriteLine("$(Get-Date -Format MM/dd/yyyy_HH:mm:ss) $_")
        }

        try {
            $sw = [System.IO.StreamWriter]::new("$using:LogDir\WeightLog_$(Get-Date -f MM-dd-yyyy).txt")
            & "$using:PlinkDir\plink.exe" -telnet $using:SerialIP -P $using:SerialPort | TimeStamp
        }
        finally {
            $sw.ForEach('Flush')
            $sw.ForEach('Dispose')
        }
    }
}

$job = CaptureWeight     # For testing, save the job
Start-Sleep -Seconds 60  # wait 1 minute
$job | Stop-Job          # kill the job
Get-Content "$LogDir\WeightLog_$(Get-Date -f MM-dd-yyyy).txt" # Did it work?
```

And the output is this:

```
05/09/2022_14:34:19   G+027800 lb
05/09/2022_14:34:20 
05/09/2022_14:34:20   G+027820 lb
05/09/2022_14:34:21 
05/09/2022_14:34:21   G+027820 lb
05/09/2022_14:34:22 
05/09/2022_14:34:22   G+027820 lb
```

Without the TimeStamp, every other line is blank. I have a couple lines to cleanup the logs, one removes every other line one removes lines with zero weights:

```
   Set-Content -Path "$LogDir\WeightLog_$(get-date -f MM-dd-yyyy).txt" -Value (get-content -Path "$LogDir\WeightLog_$(get-date -f MM-dd-yyyy).txt" | Where-Object { $i % 2 -eq 0; $i++ })

   Set-Content -Path "$LogDir\WeightLog_$(get-date -f MM-dd-yyyy).txt" -Value (get-content -Path "$LogDir\WeightLog_$(get-date -f MM-dd-yyyy).txt" | Select-String -Pattern '00000' -NotMatch)
```

If files get to be too large these can take a while to run, would be nice to not have them written to start with.

Thanks!

Edit, This is what I ended up with:

```
#****************Serial Scale Weight Logger********************

$LogDir     = "c:\ScaleWeightLogger\Logs"  # Log File Output Directory
$PlinkDir   = "c:\ScaleWeightLogger"       # plink.exe Directory
$SerialIP   = "1.1.1.1"     # Serial Device IP Address
$SerialPort = "10000"             # Serial Device Port to Log
$MakeWeight = "000\d\d\d"         # Minimum weight to log
[datetime]$JobEndTime = '23:58'   # "WeightLog" Job End Time
[datetime]$JobStartTime = '00:02' #Use '8/24/2024 03:00' for a date in the future
# https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_regular_expressions

function StartWeightCapture {
    Start-Job -Name WeightLog -ScriptBlock {
        filter timestamp {
            # Set Output Filter, Do Not Write Blank Lines or Weight Matching...
            if([string]::IsNullOrWhiteSpace($_) -or $_ -match $using:MakeWeight) {
                # skip it
                return 
        }
        # Set TimeStamp Format Filter
        $sw.WriteLine("$(Get-Date -Format MM/dd/yyyy_HH:mm:ss) $_")
    }
        try {
            # Set File Path, Set $true to Append
            $sw = [System.IO.StreamWriter]::new("$using:LogDir\WeightLog_$(Get-Date -f MM-dd-yyyy).txt", $true)
            # Keep Memory Buffer Clear After Writting
            $sw.AutoFlush = $true
            # Start plink, Filter Output, Append TimeStamp 
            & "$using:PlinkDir\plink.exe" -telnet $using:SerialIP -P $using:SerialPort | TimeStamp
        }
        finally {
            # Discard Data After Writing
            $sw.ForEach('Flush')
            $sw.ForEach('Dispose')
        }
    }
}

function WeightCaptureEndTime {
   [datetime]$CurrentTime = Get-Date
   [int]$WaitSeconds = ( $JobEndTime - $CurrentTime ).TotalSeconds
   Start-Sleep -Seconds $WaitSeconds
 }

 function StopWeightCapture {
     Stop-Job WeightLog
     $AddDaysWhenInPast = 1
     [datetime]$CurrentTime = Get-Date
     If ($JobStartTime -lt $CurrentTime) { $JobStartTime = $JobStartTime.AddDays($AddDaysWhenInPast) }
     [int]$WaitSeconds = ( $JobStartTime - $CurrentTime ).TotalSeconds
     Start-Sleep -Seconds $WaitSeconds
     
 }   

while ($true) {
    StartWeightCapture
    WeightCaptureEndTime 
    StopWeightCapture
}
```

I'm launching it at boot with:

```
powershell -windowstyle hidden -ExecutionPolicy bypass "& "C:\ScaleWeightLogger\ScaleWeightLogger.ps1"" & exit
```

And got this to end it manually since it's in the background. It only grabs the PID of the main powershell process and not the job:

```
@echo off
for /F "tokens=2" %%K in ('
   tasklist /FI "ImageName eq powershell.exe" /FI "Status eq Running" /FO LIST ^| findstr /B "PID:"
') do (
   echo "PID is %%K, Ending process..."
   taskkill /F /PID %%K
)

pause
exit
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly, adding this condition should avoid you the trouble of having to read the logs and skip the unwanted lines.

See [`String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(String)` Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.isnullorwhitespace?view=net-6.0) and [`-match` matching operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_comparison_operators?view=powershell-7.2#matching-operators) for details.

```
filter timestamp {
    # if this output is purely whitespace or it matches `00000` 
    if([string]::IsNullOrWhiteSpace($_) -or $_ -match '00000') {
        # skip it
        return 
    }
    $sw.WriteLine("$(Get-Date -Format MM/dd/yyyy_HH:mm:ss) $_")
}
```

Regarding the observation noted in previous question:

> ...when trying view the file while it's running, it seems like it updates (for viewing) about every 2 minutes, you get one 2 minute chunk of data that is about 2 minutes behind, the 2 minutes of data is there...

For this, you can enable the [`AutoFlush` property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.streamwriter.autoflush?view=net-6.0#system-io-streamwriter-autoflush) from your [`StreamWriter`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.streamwriter?view=net-6.0).

[**Remarks**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.streamwriter.autoflush?view=net-6.0#remarks) has an excellent explanation of when it's worth enabling this property as well as the performance implications:

> When `AutoFlush` is set to `false`, StreamWriter will do a limited amount of buffering, both internally and potentially in the encoder from the encoding you passed in. You can get better performance by setting `AutoFlush` to `false`, assuming that you always call `Close` (or at least `Flush`) when you're done writing with a StreamWriter.

> For example, set `AutoFlush` to `true` when you are writing to a device where the user **expects immediate feedback**. `Console.Out` is one of these cases: The StreamWriter used internally for writing to Console flushes all its internal state except the encoder state after every call to [`StreamWriter.Write`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.streamwriter.write?view=net-6.0).

```
$sw = [System.IO.StreamWriter]::new("$using:LogDir\WeightLog_$(Get-Date -f MM-dd-yyyy).txt")
$sw.AutoFlush = $true
```

Comment: it was my pleasure @Retrotube :)

Comment: @Retrotube please ask a new question. the comment section on an answer is not the best place for that. it doesnt help future readers