# How to Start-Job ForEach IP and associate IP with a name for file

Tags: arrays, powershell, object, foreach, start-job

I have a script from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72177600/how-to-ignore-lines-with-streamwriter-writeline), this is the job :

```
function CaptureWeight {
    Start-Job -Name WeightLog -ScriptBlock {
        filter timestamp {
            $sw.WriteLine("$(Get-Date -Format MM/dd/yyyy_HH:mm:ss) $_")
        }

        try {
            $sw = [System.IO.StreamWriter]::new("$using:LogDir\$FileName$(Get-Date -f MM-dd-yyyy).txt")
            & "$using:PlinkDir\plink.exe" -telnet $using:SerialIP -P $using:SerialPort | TimeStamp
        }
        finally {
            $sw.ForEach('Flush')
            $sw.ForEach('Dispose')
        }
    }
}
```

I'd like to get his to run against a list of IP addresses while also having a name associated with the IP to set the file name for each file. I was thinking something like `$Name = Myfilename` and `$name.IP = 1.1.1.1` and using those in place of $FileName and $SerialIP, but have yet to be able get anything close to working or find an example close enough to what I'm trying for.

Thanks

Comment: Have you thought about using a Hashtable for this? Something like `$lookup = @{ '1.2.3.4' = 'FileNameForThisIP'; '192.168.1.15' = 'AnotherFileNameForTHatIP' }`. Then loop over the .Keys (or use `.GetEnumerator()` and work your way through that

Comment: Is `$SerialPort` a constant value?

Comment: I agree with Theo, a hashtable would be the best approach, but also `Start-Job` is not particularly good for this since iirc you can't control the number of jobs running at the same time

Comment: If there is a network drop it doesnt matter if they are different processes or different runspaces, they will fail nonetheless

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one way you could do it with a [hash table](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_hash_tables?view=powershell-7.2) as [Theo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9898643/theo) mentioned in his helpful comment. Be aware that [Jobs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/start-job?view=powershell-7.2) don't have a **Threshold / ThrottleLimit parameter** as opposed to [`Start-ThreadJob`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/threadjob/start-threadjob?view=powershell-7.2) or [`ForEach-Object -Parallel`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/foreach-object?view=powershell-7.2#example-11-run-slow-script-in-parallel-batches) since jobs run in a different process as you have already commented instead of instances / [runspaces](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.management.automation.runspaces.runspace?view=powershellsdk-7.0.0), there is no *built-in way* to control how many Jobs can run at the same time. If you wish have control over this you would need to code it yourself.

```
# define IPs as Key and FileName as Value
$lookup = @{
    '1.2.3.4'      = 'FileNameForThisIP'
    '192.168.1.15' = 'AnotherFileNameForTHatIP'
}

# path to directory executable
$plink = 'path\to\plinkdirectory'
# path to log directory
$LogDir = 'path\to\logDirectory'
# serial port
$serialport = 123

$jobs = foreach($i in $lookup.GetEnumerator()) {
    Start-Job -Name WeightLog -ScriptBlock {
        filter timestamp {
            $sw.WriteLine("$(Get-Date -Format MM/dd/yyyy_HH:mm:ss) $_")
        }
        
        try {
            $path = Join-Path $using:LogDir -ChildPath ('{0}{1}.txt' -f $using:i.Value, (Get-Date -f MM-dd-yyyy))
            $sw = [System.IO.StreamWriter]::new($path)
            $sw.AutoFlush = $true
            & "$using:plink\plink.exe" -telnet $using:i.Key -P $using:serialPort | TimeStamp
        }
        finally {
            $sw.ForEach('Dispose')
        }
    }
}

$jobs | Receive-Job -AutoRemoveJob -Wait
```

The other alternative to the hash table could be to use a Csv (either from a file with [`Import-Csv`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/import-csv?view=powershell-7.2) or hardcoded with [`ConvertFrom-Csv`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/convertfrom-csv?view=powershell-7.2)).

Answer (score 0):

Adding here another alternative to my previous answer, using a [`RunspacePool` instance](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.management.automation.runspaces.runspacepool?view=powershellsdk-7.0.0) which has *built-in* a way of concurrency and enqueuing.

```bash
using namespace System.Management.Automation.Runspaces

try {
    # define number of threads that can run at the same time
    $threads = 10

    # define IPs as Key and FileName as Value
    $lookup = @{
        '1.2.3.4'      = 'FileNameForThisIP'
        '192.168.1.15' = 'AnotherFileNameForTHatIP'
    }

    # path to directory executable
    $plink  = 'path\to\plinkdirectory\'
    # path to log directory
    $LogDir = 'path\to\logDirectory'
    # serial port
    $port   = 123

    $iss    = [initialsessionstate]::CreateDefault2()
    $rspool = [runspacefactory]::CreateRunspacePool(1, $threads, $iss, $Host)
    $rspool.ApartmentState = 'STA'
    $rspool.ThreadOptions  = 'ReuseThread'

    # session variables that will be intialized with the runspaces
    $rspool.InitialSessionState.Variables.Add([SessionStateVariableEntry[]]@(
        [SessionStateVariableEntry]::new('plink', $plink, '')
        [SessionStateVariableEntry]::new('serialport', $port, '')
        [SessionStateVariableEntry]::new('logDir', $LogDir, '')
    ))
    $rspool.Open()

    $rs = foreach($i in $lookup.GetEnumerator()) {
        $ps = [powershell]::Create().AddScript({
            param($pair)

            filter timestamp {
                $sw.WriteLine("$(Get-Date -Format MM/dd/yyyy_HH:mm:ss) $_")
            }

            try {
                $path = Join-Path $LogDir -ChildPath ('{0}{1}.txt' -f $pair.Value, (Get-Date -f MM-dd-yyyy))
                $sw = [System.IO.StreamWriter]::new($path)
                $sw.AutoFlush = $true

                & "$plink\plink.exe" -telnet $pair.Key -P $serialPort | TimeStamp
            }
            finally {
                $sw.ForEach('Dispose')
            }
        }).AddParameter('pair', $i)

        $ps.RunspacePool = $rspool

        @{
            Instance    = $ps
            AsyncResult = $ps.BeginInvoke()
        }
    }

    foreach($r in $rs) {
        try {
            $r.Instance.EndInvoke($r.AsyncResult)
            $r.Instance.Dispose()
        }
        catch {
            Write-Error $_
        }
    }
}
finally {
    $rspool.ForEach('Dispose')
}
```

Comment: @Retrotube no, thats just format string, you dont need to change anything aside from the IPs and File Names